# Joomla Quickstart advice

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

Please I need some guidelines (or link of tutorials) in creating Joomla (3 - 3.5) website with the purchased template design. I wonder how professionals with experience are solving my doubts in practice.

1. Do you recommend the installation of the purchased blank template with a single installation and configuration of modules and components or installation of template with demo examples (Quickstart)? I know the differences but I was wondering how you are doing.
2. Till now I've almost always used the Quickstart installation.
   I wonder if you clone the main menu (and other navigation and modules) and than you rename a copy for your needs and you change the content or you delete all navigation items except Home and than you are re-creating items according to your needs.
   I'm not sure if I can copy the main menu or I copy only his necessary items and than delete overage of template. 
   It happens to me sometimes if I click on some of category it leads me to the main menu from original item, not to the desired custom copy, even though the path is set (the default items). Therefore, I am not sure which is better... copy main menu and items or to delete all navigation and content of the Quickstart installation and form my own navigation, content and modules. 
   In short, how to sort out all unnecessary items, and those that I am using should I copy and modify, modify existing, or delete all and make my own needed items.
   I believe you will know my concerns.

Thank you and regards,
John

Answer (score 1):

I have created several websites in Joomla with blank template and also with quickstart package. 
Advantages with Blank Template

1. You will get the core theme without any unnecessary content and
   basic modules and plugins. You dont have to delete any
   contents/articles later.
2. You will be having authority to place modules at your desired positions. To check the modules position at the frontend simply do this http://example.com/?tp=1.

Disadvantage of Blank Template

1. There are some module style settings embedded in quickstart package that you wont be able to set yourself without going through full documentation. So sometimes your menu seems distorted.

Disadvantage of Quickstart Package

1. Deleteing unnecessary articles, removing unnecessary modules is a big headache.
2. Database size unnecessarily increases.

Steps I follow

I create a quickstart package in localhost and create a blank site with blank template in live site. Whatever settings I need I copy from the local website so that I am saved from removing unnecessary contents from live site. Also sometimes deleting some contents give rise to some other issues. Its better t go with a Blank template.